# Jupyter Notebook kernel dies when i import model from Huggingface

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, nlp, huggingface-transformers

Here is the code where I am loading a huggingface pre trained model , but my kernel dies. The model size in the description page is only 458 MB size. Why is it failing?

```
from transformers import TextClassificationPipeline, AutoModelForSequenceClassification, AutoTokenizer
model_name = "ElKulako/cryptobert"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name, use_fast=True)
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(model_name, num_labels = 3)
pipe = TextClassificationPipeline(model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer, max_length=64, truncation=True, padding = 'max_length')
# post_1 & post_3 = bullish, post_2 = bearish
post_1 = " see y'all tomorrow and can't wait to see stock in the morning, i wonder what price it is going to be at. ,It is looking good go for it and flash by that 45k. "
df_posts = [post_1, post_2, post_3]
preds = pipe(df_posts)
print(preds)
```

[image: The model description]

Comment: its failing when I am calling model

Comment: Stack trace please. At least...

Comment: @sophros Jupyter notebook is shutting down